# how to use JavaScript to force a HTML page scroll to the top in all mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use JavaScript to scroll a HTML page scroll to the top?

Hope to implement this with an animation and make it be working in all mobile browsers. I use jQuery on that page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just [`animate`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) the [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop) property of `body` and `html` (or whatever element you have that is scrollable).

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0});
```

It is necessary to select both `body` and `html` for cross-browser support.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
$('.selector').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });
```